# How to execute a batch file on uninstall in Inno Setup?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using code from [How do you execute command line tools without using batch file in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051357/how-do-you-execute-command-line-tools-without-using-batch-file-in-inno-setup) response to execute all my batch files on installation (before, after).

Now I want to execute them **just when user click "YES" to uninstaller**, but can't find a way to do it. It executes before the confirmation

Here is my code from `[Code]` section:

```pascal
function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode : Integer;    
begin
  Result := True;
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\scripts\unset.bat'), '', '',
       SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode); 
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your code to the [`CurUninstallStepChanged(usUninstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged). That event is triggered *after* the confirmation of uninstallation.

```pascal
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  ResultCode : Integer;    
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\scripts\unset.bat'), '', '',
         SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode); 
  end;
end;
```

---

Though it's easier to use [`[UninstallRun]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection).

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\scripts\unset.bat"; Flags: runhidden
```

The section is also processed after the confirmation, but before any files are uninstalled. See [Uninstallation order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31456897/850848).

---

*Note that in general, you should not use batch files. You better script everything in Pascal code. That way you get much more robust code and better error handling.*

*Note that ironically, the question you point to was asked to [avoid using batch files in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27992605/850848#comment44380458_27992699).*